# Thumbnails images on Jssor sliders have null src property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jssor

Using jssor sliders with thumbnails, i populate the **ng-src** path attribute of the  images from a database :

```
<div data-ng-repeat="img in resp.records">
        <img u="image" ng-src="{{ img.img }}"/>
        <img u="thumb" ng-src="{{ img.thumb }}"/>
</div>
```

The code above is further interpreted by a [Js](https://jsfiddle.net/ozopxmno/) file made by Jssor.com which transforms it into the code below which works fine for the images part according to the browser :

```
<img u="image" ng-src="img/A01.jpg" src="img/A01.jpg">
```

but not for the thumbnails part which is shown in the browser like below :

```
<img u="thumb" ng-src="" src="null">
```

I didn't mention any **src** tag above (but only **ng-src**) because of the expression between {{ }} that has to be interpreted by AngularJs.

**UPDATE**:
Here what the `img.img` and `img.thumb` contain:

```
{"records":[{"img":"img/A01.jpg","thumb": "img/thumbs/A01.jpg"},{"img":"img/A02.jpg","thumb": "img/thumbs/A02.jpg"}]}
```

**EDIT**:
As per requested by Jssor's team, below the final `html` rendered by Angular regarding the thumbnail part:

```
<div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort02" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 240px; height: 720px;" jssor-slider="true">
    <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->

    <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 240px; height: 720px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: scale(1);"><div class="jssort02" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px; display: block; position: relative; top: 0px; overflow: visible;"><div u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 47px; top: 319.5px; width: 146px; height: 81px; z-index: 0;"><div debug-id="slide_container" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; pointer-events: none; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div></div><div u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 47px; top: 319.5px; width: 146px; height: 81px; z-index: 0;" debug-id="slide-board"><div style="width: 146px; height: 81px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>

    <div debug-id="slide-0" style="width: 146px; height: 81px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;"><div u="prototype" class="p pdn" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <div class="w">
                <img u="thumb" ng-src="" class="t" style="display: block;" src="null">
            </div>
            <div class="c"></div>
        </div><div style="width: 146px; height: 81px; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1000; display: none;"></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: It seems that img.thumb is null. Is the img object initialized correctly?

Comment: img.thumb returns some values but is not interpreted well by the Js.

Comment: But what's the value of `img.thumb`?

Comment: Please post the final html code that rendered by angular.

Comment: The problem is that `src` is invalid in the html code generated by angular. `<img u="thumb" ng-src="" class="t" style="display: block;" src="null">`

Comment: However, it seems to be valid for the   <code><img u="image" ng-src="img/A01.jpg" src="img/A01.jpg"></code>   although generated by Angular the same way. Should the thumbnail part work the same ? Would a patch may be considered to fix the problem? Thanks for the reply @jssor

Comment: You see, angular and your template html codes should work correctly first. And then jssor slider can work after that. That's to say, it's not business of jssor slider. If you remove all jssor codes,angular would not generate right html codes.

Comment: Angular works perfectly. As an edit I mentioned the returned values in an array. I assume that if I didn't mention any `src` for the first statement (but an `ng-src`) and jssor sliders has generated the right related `html` code populating the `src` attribute, why does jssor sliders don't populate the `src` attribute for the thumbnail part (second statement)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work well if the urls are correct, maybe there is another problem not related to Angular.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('Main', function($scope) {
  $scope.resp = {
    "records": [{
      "img": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/128/Status-user-online-icon.png",
      "thumb": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/32/Status-user-online-icon.png"
    }, {
      "img": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/3d-social/128/Online-writing-icon.png",
      "thumb": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/3d-social/32/Online-writing-icon.png"
    }]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main">
  <div data-ng-repeat="img in resp.records">
    <img u="image" ng-src="{{ img.img }}" />
    <img u="thumb" ng-src="{{ img.thumb }}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess the problem is related to the Js file made by Jssor.com which seems to be very tricky. I'm waiting for the Jssor's teams to reply. Thanks @Michael